# cakephp model association/join with same table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a table that contains parents and children. I want to be able to build the model so that it returns the parents and their children i.e it associates with itself.

```
ID Name ParentID
1  Parent  0
2  Child1  1
3  Child2  1
4  Parent2 0
5  Child3  4
```

I use the following SQL

```
SELECT
 grp2.id,
 grp2.name
FROM wp_bp_groups grp1
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_groups grp2
 ON grp2.parent_id = grp1.id
WHERE grp1.id = '$parent_id'
ORDER BY grp2.name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php  
class Group extends AppModel { 

 var $name = 'Group'; 

 var $belongsTo = array( 
        'ParentGroup' => 
            array('className' => 'Group', 
                  'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' 
        ), 
     ); 

 var $hasMany = array( 
    'ChildGroup' => 
            array('className' => 'Group', 
                  'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' 
            ), 
    ); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! What if i want to return the groups in a better structured way, like a tree hierarchy. The answer below mentions tree behavior, but what if i don't want to change the schema. I want to mimic the tree behavior. Right now it returns all groups, including children which have empty child group arrays. I was thinking of possibly rebuilding the array inside the model, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: found find('threaded'). That actually makes your solution redundant.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that might be a more elegant solution to your problem - didn't want to suggest it or Tree behaviour because I haven't really used them myself.  Must investigate for myself sometime though!

Comment: But how to fill select box with all parent_id to select from? i.e. if group gas (a,b,c) then how to make select box like this when adding record `<select name="parent_id"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select>`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Tree behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1339/Tree), which allows easy management of [hierarchical data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).